# Public method works in its class but not on another what's going on?

Tags: c#, xna

I created a method on a ballsprite class that tells me if there was a collision.
It should return a bool value; the problem is when I call it from a scene class it calls the method and all but when I tell it to set ball's `visible = false` it doesn't do it.
So I created it as an attribute on the `BallSprite` class and set it to false there, any idea why it happens the way it does?

This is the relevant code:

```
public bool isvisible = true; //this is the attribute I added

public bool is_ballCrash() //this checks for collision
    {
        int maxY = game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - ballSprite.Height;
        return (ballPosition.Y > maxY);                       
    }   

if(is_ballCrash())   //this is is_ballCrash usage
        {
            //crashSound.Play();
            ballPosition.Y = 0;
            ballSpeed.X = 150;
            ballSpeed.Y = 150;
            isvisible = false; //***
        }
```

Now on my scene calss:
when I add this on the update method it works:

```
if (ballSprite.isvisible == false)
            ballSprite.Visible = false;
```

But this doesn't work and this is what I dun get:

```
if (ballSprite.is_ballCrash() == true)
        {ballSprite.Visible = false;}
```

It DOES return a true value (the ball is getting reset in its y position so the class itself works).
The problem is entering the method in the scene the `if` gets it's true value (or at least it should since the method returns it) but does not execute the block.
I tried other code lines like:

```
ballSprite.ballSpeed.X -= 1000;
```

But it doesn't reach it (does not stop on breakpoint)

I don't comprehend how the method returns true and does what it should on the sprite class but not on the update method of the scene class it should get the same value.
Unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Your question is really unclear, where is the problem exactly? this doesn't work is not descriptive enough at all..

Comment: You wrote that the program doesn't stop at the breakpoint, are you sure that ballSprite.is_ballCrash() is calling the method you think? Are you inheriting from another class?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know

- this.isvisible = false; in your class
- public property Visible are somehow not linked.

you can test this easily by making a function in your class

```
public void TestVisible()
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(this.isvisible == this.Visible);
}
```

and call it from

```
if (ballSprite.is_ballCrash() == true)
{
    ballSprite.Visible = false;
    ballSprite.TestVisible();
}
```

You should get an assert error

Comment: I added iavisible because the ballsprite.visible did not work.

Comment: I will try to get it simple:
I have a method (is_ballCrash()) in a class called BallSpritre.
When I call it from BallSprite's update() it works fine and returns the right value.

BUT when I invoke it from another class (scene1) using the BallSprite's instance (ballSprite.is_ballCrash()) it alwyas returns false (or so it would seem).

So I went on and bypassed it by created indicator by teh name isvisible...
I dun get why it doesn;t work when invoked from scene1

Comment: I'd like to help you but I think the problem does not lie in the code you provided. if you send your project to me at Napivo [at] gmail.com I will take a look and tell you what you have done wrong.